# Latexdiff - mark manually a table as added

Tags: latexdiff

I have used latexdiff to show the differences between two documents. Now I want to add a table in the diff-file and mark it as added (blue color with underline). How can I do this?

I have tried:

```
%\DIFadd{
\begin{table*}[!htb]
\end{table*}
}
```

However, this doesn't work. Ideas?

Comment: Welcome. // You can use a package like proofread: https://www.ctan.org/pkg/proofread and mark your edits. Or use package changes, or any other from this category: https://www.ctan.org/topic/editorial .

Comment: Thank you very much. However, is it possinbe to add it manually with the latexdiff commands?

Comment: Looks like: search for DIFadd or add in the manual https://www.ctan.org/pkg/latexdiff . You may also want to have a look here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/latexdiff .

Comment: \begin{table} simply indicates a float environment - as you have written it, there is nothing to mark. You need to give more details on the use case, especially why not just let latexdiff figure out the correct way to highlight the table by putting it into the 'new' file directly and then processing. Also provide a more complete MWE (minimum working example) with actually some text to highlight